# How to unfold the definition of sequenceA, and where its recursive base case is?

Tags: haskell

It's very fantastic that `sequenceA` function can reverse the container of a variable -- for instance, running `sequence (Just $ Right 3)` will get `Right $ Just 3`. I want to unfold `sequenceA` to see how it works, but I get sucked into it...

```
-- source code of `sequenceA` for reference
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f

sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA = traverse id

-- unfold it
> sequenceA (Just $ Right 3)
> (traverse id) (Just $ Right 3)
> (sequenceA . fmap id) (Just $ Right 3)
> sequenceA (fmap id (Just $ Right 3))
> (traverse id) (fmap id (Just $ Right 3))
> (sequenceA . fmap id) (fmap id (Just $ Right 3))
> traverse id . fmap id . fmap id $ Just (Right 3)
-- and so on...
> traverse id . fmap id . fmap id . fmap id $ Just (Right 3)
> traverse id . fmap id . fmap id . fmap id . fmap id $ Just (Right 3)
......
```

Where is the recursive base case?

Comment: A type that’s a `Traversable` has to implement at least one of `traverse` or `sequenceA`. The default definitions are ways of deriving the functionality of one from the other,

Comment: Oh my god, get it...thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A type that’s a `Traversable` has to implement at least one of `traverse` or `sequenceA`. The default definitions are ways of deriving the functionality of one from the other.

[Here’s `Maybe`’s `Traversable` implementation:](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#line-230)

```
instance Traversable Maybe where
    traverse _ Nothing = pure Nothing
    traverse f (Just x) = Just <$> f x
```

Now you can expand `sequenceA (Just (Right 3))` to `traverse id (Just (Right 3))` = `Just <$> id (Right 3)` = `Just <$> Right 3` = `Right (Just 3)`.